# Sexual abstinence after varicocele embolization

Tags: urology

I'm reading about varicocele embolization and I've read that after the procedure it is recommended to stop sexual activity for 2 to 4 weeks.
However, no one explain why the sexual activity could interfere with the procedure itself. What is the correlation?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions on Medical Sciences are required to show prior research. As described in [the help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: Common sense says that the reason is to prevent risk of the surgery to fail due to excessive blood pressure in the veins that have been treated during the surgery. Only a comment as I did not perform real research, but it can give you direction, at least.